# Datagrid within ReferenceManyField showing rows but no data

Tags: react-admin

RA newbe. Please go easy on me.

I have a tabbedshowlayout with two tabs. Both tabs contain a ReferenceManyField:

```
     <SimpleShowLayout>
            <TabbedShowLayout>
                    <Tab label="Store(s)">
                        <ReferenceManyField label="Stores" reference="stores" target="data0">
                            <Datagrid optimized rowClick="show" >
                                <TextField source="name"/>
                                <TextField source="storeStatus"/>
                                <DateField source="updatedAt" locales="en-UK"/>
                                <EditButton/>
                            </Datagrid>
                        </ReferenceManyField>
                    </Tab>
                    <Tab label="Contact(s)">
                        <ReferenceManyField label="Contacts" reference="contacts" target="data1">
                            <Datagrid optimized>
                                <TextField source="id"/>
                                <TextField source="firstName"/>
                                <TextField source="lastName"/>
                                <TextField source="phone"/>
                                <BooleanField source="financeContact"/>
                            </Datagrid>
                        </ReferenceManyField>
                    </Tab>
             </TabbedShowLayout>
    </SimpleShowLayout>
```

[The first ReferenceManyField's datagrid displays data as expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03Upx.png)

[The second ReferenceManyField's datagrid displays the correct number of rows, but no data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJWlc.png)

I cannot see any difference between how the two objects are handled. I should add that the dataProvider has been thoroughly tested and is delivering the data as required.
Has anyone else run into a problem like this?

All hints & tips greatly appreciated. If no solution, then a hint on how to dig deeper into RA...

Comment: Your code seems correct. Does removing the optimized option change anything? If not, please try replicating your problem with the react-admin CodeSandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/github/marmelab/react-admin/tree/master/examples/simple) so that we can check your code.

Comment: It's taken me a little while, but I have created a stripped-down version of my app that demonstrates the problem: https://vghuj.csb.app/
Login is fake. Any credentials will do.
A single "company" is listed. CompanyShow.tsx has a tabbed view, which should display data fetched via getManyReference. 
getManyReference does indeed successfully fetch the data, yet it is not rendered correctly.
Interestingly, of the two tabs the first tab's data IS rendered correctly in MY environment. 
Any advice greatly received.

Answer (score 0):

Not the solution to the problem, but the source code to accompany the above working example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-admin-referencemanyfield-issue-vghuj
Again: Any credentials sill suffice for logging into the working example.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined a `<Resource>` for the *stores* resource. This is required for `<ReferenceManyField>` to work, [as explained in the documentation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Fields.html#referencemanyfield):

> Note: You must add a `<Resource>` for the reference resource - react-admin needs it to fetch the reference data. You can omit the list prop in this reference if you want to hide it in the sidebar menu.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Admin authProvider={authProvider} dataProvider={dataProvider}>
      <Resource name="companies" {...companies} />
+     <Resource name="stores"  />
    </Admin>
  );
}
```

By the way, you're using a `<TabbedShowLayout>` inside a `<SimpleShowLayout>`, this isn't supported.